# Unable to translate "Insert" and "Cancel" buttons on insert link popup while editing the tag description

Tags: bug, status-review, tag-wiki, editor, localization

Editor used for modifying [tag description](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/42) has an (very) old design. In that design it's not possible to make translations for buttons "Insert" and "Cancel":

> [image: Insert hyperlink]

Comment: Strange indeed. I've passed this on to the devs (and I found the relevant bit of the code that controls the text for these buttons, so it should make it easier to fix).